# Mysql have suddenly started regularly opening unsuccessful sockets

Tags: mysql, sockets, resource-leak

I've desperately tried to figure out what's happened here, but haven't seen this particular problem anywhere. I've 'inherited' (as in, not built any of it myself) management of a database server (remote, in a data warehouse, accessed by ssh) where some php daemons are running on a Linux server acting as data crawlers, inserting and processing information in a relatively steady stream into mysql.

A couple of days ago, the server crashed and came back on again. I logged in an restarted the mysql server and the crawlers, thinking no more of it. A day and a half later, the mysql server stopped working, and I couldn't diagnose it since I couldn't log into it, nor did it respond to "/etc/init.d/mysql stop" or varieties thereof. According to the log file, it kept throwing errors very regularly (once every four minutes and 16 seconds) and said that it had too many file handlers open. When I shut down the crawlers, however, I could log in again, but mysql kept throwing the errors.  I checked lsof and it showed a lot of open sockets with "can't identify protocol" error.

> mysqld  28843 mysql 1990u  sock        0,4              2856488 can't identify protocol
>
> mysqld  28843 mysql 1989u  sock        0,4              2857220 can't identify protocol

^Thousands of these rows

I thought it was something the crawlers had done, and I restarted mysql and the failed sockets disappeared. But I was surprised to see that mysql kept opening new ones, even when the crawlers weren't running. It did this very regularly, about two new failed sockets a minute, regardless of whether the crawlers were active or not. I increased the maximum amount of filehandlers allowed for mysql to buy some time, but I'm obviously looking for a diagnosis and permanent solution.

All descriptions of such errors (socket leaks) that I've found on forums seems to be about your own software leaking, not closing its sockets. But this seems to be mysql itself that does it, and there has been no change in any of the code from when it worked fine, just a server crash and restart.

Any ideas?